# Need to set a date parameter on an SSRS subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, subscription

I have a report in SSRS that takes a single date as a parameter.  What I want is for that report to have a subscription that uses the Saturday of two weeks ahead as the date (i.e., Monday 7/4 would give Saturday 7/16).  How can I do this in the subscription? Looks like I can't do a formula in the parameter.

Comment: You can also do this using a data-driven subscription. You would provide a query that calculates the date you want and then set that as the parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the default parameter value in the report, not in the subscription. An expression to use in the default for the date parameter would look something like this. There both add 2 weeks to the current date.

```
=DataAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, 2, Today)
```

or

```
=Today.AddDays(14)
```

The default values can be set using the Report Parameters Properties dialog in the report designer. Just double-click on the parameter you want to change and the dialog will open.